# What happens to Personal Access Tokens when GitHub user converted to organization?

Tags: github

What happens to Personal Access Tokens when GitHub user converted to organization?  We have a few applications where private repos are installed directly from GitHub  using Personal Access Tokens.  The `package.json` looks like this...

```
"dependencies": {
    "async": "^2.1.5",
    "my-repo": "git+https://<PERSONAL ACCESS TOKEN>:x-oauth-basic@github.com/myaccount/my-repo" ,
 },...
```

If we convert "myaccount" to an organization, do those break?

Answer (score 1):

[Converting a user into an organization](https://help.github.com/articles/converting-a-user-into-an-organization/) will invalidate user-specific information, including OAuth tokens.

> Warning: Before converting a user into an organization, keep these points in mind:
>
> - The SSH keys, OAuth tokens, job profile, and associated user information, will not be transferred to the organization. This is only true for the user account that's being converted, not any of the user account's collaborators.

Here is the UI:

[image]